# Getting an error after execution as FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeTest Login

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, selenium2, testng

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property; for more information, see https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver. The latest version can be downloaded from http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:754)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.findExecutable(DriverService.java:124)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.access$000(ChromeDriverService.java:32)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService$Builder.findDefaultExecutable(ChromeDriverService.java:137)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:329)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.createDefaultService(ChromeDriverService.java:88)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:124)
    at Registration.Validuser.Login(Validuser.java:17)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:108)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:523)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:224)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:146)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.beforeRun(TestRunner.java:658)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:626)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:425)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:420)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:385)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:334)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1318)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1243)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1161)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1129)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:114)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)


===============================================
    Default test
    Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
    Configuration Failures: 1, Skips: 0
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, *a specific problem or error* and the *shortest code necessary* to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

As It is clearly showing :

> Java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path to the driver executable
>   must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property; for more
>   information, see
>   https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver

That means you have set path of `chromedriver.exe` to run your test in Chrome Browser.

You need to do :

1. Navigate [here](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) and download latest `chromedriver.exe` as per your system and Google chrome version you are using
2. You need to set the properties for `chromedriver`. Mention below code before open chrome browser

   ```
   System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","c:\\chromedriver.exe");
   WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
   ```
3. For the Firefox browser you need to download latest `geckodriver` , and set property as `webdriver.gecko.driver`

Answer (score 0):

You are missing to add `ChromeDriver` , download it from [here](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/) and unzip at set the path using `setProperty()`

Try this code:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","Your path of chromedriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver()
```